# ASP.NET Login with Email/Password

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

In ASP.NET 4.0,

I would like to be able to login a user via email and password only, not username.

The CreateUserWizards also have a notion of only creating users via username and not by email.

Is it possible to login someone with just email/password on ASP.NET?

Comment: Just use the email address as the username.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. Check out the following:

[Using Email to Login with ASP.NET Membership](http://www.jimandkatrin.com/CodeBlog/post/Using-Email-to-Login-with-ASPNET-Membership.aspx)

[Set email address as username in ASP.NET Membership provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498741/set-email-address-as-username-in-asp-net-membership-provider)