# How to add users to roles by id or email

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using simple membership provider. It works great so far. [System.Web.Security.Roles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles.aspx)
provides a convenient method to [AddUserToRole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles.addusertorole.aspx).

AddUserToRole accepts two parameters:

1. username
2. roleName

I have two questions:

1. One of the roles in my system is created manually by administrator,
   and doesn't have any username (null). I still want to assign those
   users to a role. Something like AddUserToRole(UserId, RoleName). How
   can I overload that?
2. Is it possible to use email instead of username out of the box? if so, how would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create your own provider and inherit from Asp.Net Membership provider. There you could provide your own overloads for the methods. Here is an example of another question where someone wanted to use email as user name. Hope it helps. [Set email address as username in ASP.NET Membership provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498741/set-email-address-as-username-in-asp-net-membership-provider)