# Is it possible to change username types for asp.net membership provider?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf

Is it possible to change the way users create accounts for an SQL membership provider, so that users have to sign up with their email as their username? I know by default users can make their username in email format but then it still asks for the email address twice ontop of the username which makes it a little redundant.

Comment: Possibly this previous [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498741/set-email-address-as-username-in-asp-net-membership-provider) could help? However, it does look like the provider was extended because the behaviour did not exist natively in there to do this....

Comment: Thanks nkvu, that definitely helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't ask the user his `UserName` while registering. Ask the Email address and pass email address in place of `UserName` in `CreateUser()` method.

```
Membership.CreateUser(PASSEMAILIDHERE, model.Password, model.Email, null, null, true, null, out createStatus);
```

Comment: That seems like a fairly simple way to go about it. Thanks. The only issue I see with this approach after doing more research is that the username table in the database doesn't allow as many characters as the username table does. Although that is an easy fix. Thanks again.